# Python Index out of range

Tags: python

Can someone help me solve this problem?

I just solved the index out of range problem.

Can someone tell me what to do, if I want to keep current changes(booked seat) that user has made? Every time a run the program the seat will be all available..

Thanks in advance

```
seats = []
seats.append(["A1","A2","A3","A4","A5"])
seat = []
seat.append([0,0,0,0,0])
for row in seats :
    print(row)
booked = False
while booked == False :
    answer_1 = str(input("Please enter seat: "))
    if answer_1 == "A1":
        row=0
        column=0
        if seat[row][column]=="X":
            print("Occupied !")
        else :
            print("Booking ...")
            seat[row][column]="X"
            seats[row][column]="X"
            print ("Done !")
            booked = True
```

Comment: please add code sample here directly, not by link.

Comment: Copy and paste both the code *AND* the traceback and error message into the question.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience, edited !

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the list `seat` when printed:

```
seat = []
seat.append([0,0,0,0,1])
print(seat) 
#Output: [[0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

It is a list with only 1 item, another list which itself has 5 items. If you assign the integer 1 to both `row` and `column` and attempt to access `seat[row][column]` as you do in your code, the first index tries to access a non-existent second item in `seat` and gives you the error.

To access an integer from the list within the list `seat`, the `row` variable must be 0 as your code currently stands. For instance, `seat[0][1]` will give you the second 0 in the list within `seat`.

Comment: so, is there any way to access the first 0 ?

Comment: and is there any way to replace the list with "X" after they book the place

Comment: @DeltaTroz You can access the first 0 with seat[0][0]. 

seat[0] gets the list, and adding another [0] will get you the first item in the list, the 0.

If you want to replace the entire list with the string "X", you can rebind the seat variable to it: seat = "X". If you want to maintain seat as a list and just replace all the items with the single item "X", you can use seat[0] = "X". The former makes seat = "X", the latter makes it a list with a single item: seat = ["X"].